# Sql find another tables with same value and add their ID in output

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I've got the following two SQL tables (in MySQL):

```
 Posts Tables
 +----+---------------+--------+----------+ 
 | id | title         |  slug  | language |
 +----+---------------+--------+----------+ 
 | 1  | Post title    | slug_1 |  eng     |
 | 2  | Another title | slug_2 |  eng     |
 | 3  | Title German  | slug_1 |  ger     |
 | 4  | Again German  | slug_3 |  ger     |
 | 5  | Russian title | slug_1 |  rus     |
 +----+---------------+--------+----------+
```

In output i am have to get list of all Posts and in the same line of array the information of other posts (id) where slug is same. Something like this

```
 +----+------------+--------+----------+--------------+---------------+
 | id | title      |  slug  | language | german trans | russian trans |
 +----+------------+--------+----------+--------------+---------------+
 | 1  | Post title | slug_1 |  eng     | 3            | 5
 | 2  | Another ti | slug_2 |  eng     | null         | null
 | 4  | German tit | slug_3 |  null    | 4            | null
```

First i decided do this-sorting after getting list of posts with foreach loop but it takes a really big resource when list of posts is big. so i think in sql it will be much faster but i dont know i to do this.

Comment: "two tables" ? Your question only has one.  Why is the language for "4" `NULL` instead of `'ger'`?

Comment: Because there could be a post that does not exist in the native language of the website which is English but exists in German. And there is no need to display that post in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want the first post, along with information about translations.  If you know the languages then this probably does what you want:

```
select s.minid,
       max(case when p.id = s.minid then title end) as title,
       s.slug,
       max(case when p.id = s.minid then language end) as language,
       max(case when p.lang = 'ger' then id end) as German,
       max(case when p.lang = 'rus' then id end) as Russian
from posts p join
     (select slug, min(id) as minid
      from posts p
      group by slug
     ) s
     on p.slug = s.slug
group by p.slug;
```